# How can I synchronize Starbound savegame for multiple users on multiple computers?

Tags: starbound

Here's my situation:

- 2 users play starbound on multiple computers (2 desktops)
- sometimes we play multiplayer together, each on 1 desktop
- I want to sync my savegames so I can pick up on any of the computers when playing single player

Is this even possible with Starbound?

If I would play always single player with only my own character, I can sync my savegames by copying the *storage* directory from the `SteamApps` directory to the computers. But as the universe is shared, if the other user played inbetween, I would overwrite the state of some of the planets when I copy files over from the other computer. Is my understanding correct? If yes, is there any way to solve this?

Comment: dropbox probably

Answer (score 2):

The ideal way is to set up Dropbox to sync the files between your computers.

Download and install [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install) on both computers, you'll need to [create an account](https://www.dropbox.com/login) if you don't have one already and sign into both computers with the same account. On the computer with the newest copy of the world, move it from SteamApps into Dropbox (I recommend having everything be in a subfolder, as in, Dropbox -> Files -> Every file and folder that you want to sync).

Then, you'll need to create symlinks. You'll want to symlink the game directory into Dropbox, so open a command prompt or terminal and navigate to where your storage directory was and use the command `mklink /J storage C:\Users\[username]\Dropbox\Files\storage` for Windows or `ln -s /home/[username]/Dropbox/Files/storage` for Linux (similar command on Mac). Repeat on the other computer, deleting the existing "storage" in SteamApps on that computer first, so that you can create the link.

Now, you should be good to go as long as you two don't accidentally play at the same time or play without an internet connection (and therefore no syncing). If you screw up your save somehow, you can restore individual files to previous versions from Dropbox's site, but in general I recommend keeping backups.

Comment: Well, exactly the last paragraph is the core of my problem. I already sync the files with bittorrent sync, but when we are both playing (multiplayer or not) the savegame will get messed up, right?

Comment: You _should_ be fine if you both play at the same time as long as one of you hosts and the other joins. The problems arise when two people try to host. I say should since I don't play Starbound myself but I do use this method for Minecraft / Terraria / Space Engineers / other games just fine.